# OpenSSH 7.3p1 building: configure only finds an old version of OpenSSL libraries

Tags: linux, build, openssl, openssh, rhel5

I'm trying to build **OpenSSH 7.3p1** in a Linux box which has got installed an old OpenSSL version.

First of all I have successfully compiled **OpenSSL 1.0.2h** and installed in `/opt/openssh-1.0.2h`, not in `/usr` where resides the old OpenSSL version.

```
tar xzf openssl-1.0.2h.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.0.2h
./config --prefix=/opt/openssl-1.0.2h shared
make depend
make
make test
make install
```

Then I proceed with OpenSSH:

```
tar xzf openssh-7.3p1.tar.gz
cd openssh-7.3p1
./configure --prefix=/opt/openssh-7.3p1 --with-openssl=/opt/openssl-1.0.2h
```

But the `configure` scripts fails with the following error message:

```
checking OpenSSL header version... 0090802f (OpenSSL 0.9.8e-rhel5 01 Jul 2008)
checking OpenSSL library version... configure: error: OpenSSL >= 0.9.8f required (have "0090802f (OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008)")
```

The same message is displayed if I use `--with-ssl-dir=/opt/openssl-1.0.2h/ssl`

The tool `findssl.sh` (found in the subdirectory `contrib`) can find properly all OpenSSL versions. And its notes inside (comments) suggest to use **CFLAGS** to point out the desired library -- I quote:

```
# Now run findssl.sh. This should identify the headers and libraries
# present  and  their  versions.  You  should  be  able  to identify the
# libraries  and headers used and adjust your CFLAGS or remove incorrect
# versions.  The  output will show OpenSSL's internal version identifier
# and should look something like:
```

Then I tried

```
./configure CFLAGS="-I/opt/openssl-1.0.2h/include" --prefix=/opt/openssh-7.3p1  --with-openssl=/opt/openssl-1.0.2h
```

This appears to work because it finds the new **OpenSSL** header version:

```
checking OpenSSL header version... 1000208f (OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016)
checking OpenSSL library version... configure: error: OpenSSL >= 0.9.8f required (have "0090802f (OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008)")
```

Next step would be to supply additional options to locate the library files. But if I add `LDFLAGS='-L/opt/openssl-1.0.2h/lib'` or `--with-ldflags='-L/opt/openssl-1.0.2h/lib'`, this is what I get:

```
checking OpenSSL header version... not found
configure: error: OpenSSL version header not found.
```

In summary, I do not know **how to make `configure` use the new OpenSSL libraries**.

**update 1**: if `--with-ldflags='-L/opt/openssl-1.0.2h/ssl'` is used instead of `···openssl-1.0.2h/lib` then header version check works properly (see a few lines above), library version check still fails though.

**update 2**: I traced the problem and found it is related to shared libraries. From the `config.log` file I got the source code files `conftest.c` and `confdef.h` and the options used to build the runnable `conftest`:

```
#include "confdefs.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/opensslv.h>
#include <openssl/crypto.h>
#define DATA "conftest.ssllibver"

int
main ()
{

  FILE *fd;
  int rc;

  fd = fopen(DATA,"w");
  if (fd == NULL)
     exit(1);

  if ((rc = fprintf(fd, "%08lx (%s)\n", (unsigned long)SSLeay(),
                    SSLeay_version(SSLEAY_VERSION))) < 0)
     exit(1);

  exit(0);
}
```

This program stores the OpenSSL version as text in the file `conftest.ssllibver`. For debugging purposes I turned `fprint(fd,` into `print(` to print the data into the terminal.

The command line used to build the `conftest` program is:

```
# gcc -o conftest -I/opt/openssl-1.0.2h/include -Wall \
-Wpointer-arith -Wsign-compare -Wformat-security -Wno-pointer-sign \
-fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -ftrapv -fno-builtin-memset \
-fstack-protector-all -std=gnu99 -fPIE -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now \ 
-Wl,-z,noexecstack -fstack-protector-all -pie conftest.c \
-lcrypto -lrt -ldl -lutil -lz

# ldd conftest |grep libcrypto
       libcrypto.so.6 => /lib64/libcrypto.so.6 (0x00002b5fc6c3e000)
```

Uses the old OpenSSL library.

When `-L/opt/openssl-1.0.2h/lib` is added as an argument, `conftest` cannot run because the **dynamic loader** (`ld.so`) cannot find `libcrypto.so.1.0.0`:

```
# ./conftest
./conftest: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
# ldd conftest | grep libcrypto
        libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => not found
```

But when I make the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable point to `/opt/openssl-1.0.2h/lib`, the dynamic loader finds the library file `libcrypto.so.1.0.0` and thus the executable `conftest` works properly -- it uses the new OpenSSL library:

```
# export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/openssl-1.0.2h/lib
# ./conftest
1000208f (OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016)
# ldd conftest
        libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /opt/openssl-1.0.2h/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00002b450bf97000)
```

Comment: Also see [Building OpenSSH for OS X?](http://superuser.com/a/961422/173513) on Super User. It includes the recipe I used. I've used the general recipe for OS X and Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Export the **`LD_LIBRARY_PATH`** environment variable, which must hold the directory where **new OpenSSL library files** are, and run the `configure` script:

```
# export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/openssl-1.0.2h/lib
# ./configure CFLAGS="-I/opt/openssl-1.0.2h/include" \
--prefix=/opt/openssh-7.3p1 \
--with-ldflags="-L/opt/openssl-1.0.2h/lib"
```

Both commands can also be joined in just one:

```
# LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/openssl-1.0.2h/lib ./configure \
CFLAGS="-I/opt/openssl-1.0.2h/include" \
--prefix=/opt/openssh-7.3p1 \
--with-ldflags="-L/opt/openssl-1.0.2h/lib"
```

And this is the outcome:

```
OpenSSH has been configured with the following options:
                     User binaries: /opt/openssh-7.3p1/bin
                   System binaries: /opt/openssh-7.3p1/sbin
               Configuration files: /opt/openssh-7.3p1/etc
                   Askpass program: /opt/openssh-7.3p1/libexec/ssh-askpass
                      Manual pages: /opt/openssh-7.3p1/share/man/manX
                          PID file: /var/run
  Privilege separation chroot path: /var/empty
            sshd default user PATH: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/openssh-7.3p1/bin
                    Manpage format: doc
                       PAM support: no
                   OSF SIA support: no
                 KerberosV support: no
                   SELinux support: no
                 Smartcard support: 
                     S/KEY support: no
              MD5 password support: no
                   libedit support: no
  Solaris process contract support: no
           Solaris project support: no
         Solaris privilege support: no
       IP address in $DISPLAY hack: no
           Translate v4 in v6 hack: yes
                  BSD Auth support: no
              Random number source: OpenSSL internal ONLY
             Privsep sandbox style: rlimit

              Host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
          Compiler: gcc
    Compiler flags: -I/opt/openssl-1.0.2h/include -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wsign-compare \
                    -Wformat-security -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-aliasing \
                    -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -ftrapv -fno-builtin-memset -fstack-protector-all \
                    -std=gnu99 -fPIE 
Preprocessor flags: 
      Linker flags:  -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,-z,noexecstack -fstack-protector-all \
                     -L/opt/openssl-1.0.2h/lib -pie
         Libraries: -lcrypto -lrt -ldl -lutil -lz  -lcrypt -lresolv
```

It is highly recommended to use the **`LD_LIBRARY_PATH`** in the next steps `make` and `make install`; otherwise the `make install` will fail because the `ssh-keygen` command is run to generate the new host keys and it will not find the new OpenSSH library files:

```
mkdir /opt/openssh-7.3p1/etc
./ssh-keygen: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
make: *** [host-key] Error 127
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use the `--with-ssl-dir` option for openssh's configure script:

```
$ ./configure --help | grep with-ssl-dir
  --with-ssl-dir=PATH     Specify path to OpenSSL installation
```

The `--with-openssl` option is just a boolean flag that enables or disables the `openssl` dependency.

Comment: Yes,you are right -- **`--with-openssl`** is just a boolean flag. But the `--with-ssl-dir` option does not get rid of the OpenSSL library version check error.

Comment: I initally used `--with-openssl` because I recently compiled and built **bind** using that flag and, in that case, it was not just a boolean flag: `--with-openssl=PATH               Build with OpenSSL yes|no|path.`

Comment: If `--with-ssl-dir` does not work, maybe you ask in the openssl mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39347023/1575353) provided by [@Jdamain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2545194/jdamian), I needed to recompile openssl setting both `--prefix` and `--openssldir` to the same directory.